# How to evaluate a custom expression in debug in JDeveloper

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, expression, jdeveloper

In Eclipse you can write a random expression in debug and it evaluates it.
This is my code:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
     int x = 3;
*    System.out.print(x);
}
```

in the breakpoint I want to watch the expression

> x

Then it shows 3.

But if I watch a custom expression like:

> new java.util.Date()

which should return the current date, it displays

> ?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you use the inspect option in debug mode?

Comment: no, only if the expression was present in the code, or if I navigate inside the object via Reflexion, to see it's fields, not what its methods return. And this is what I want

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that it doesn't let you invoke constructors, at least not directly. However, you can be a bit devious and use reflection, i.e.

```
Class.forName("java.util.Date").newInstance()
```

as your watch expression gives you a new Date.

Possibly not quite on a par with what Eclipse lets you do, but still useful for some things.